# Laravel 5.1 - Redirecting specific users on every page

Tags: routes, laravel-5.1, redirect

I'm making a website where users can register before it launches. However when people with a specific email adress register they can already have acces to the full website, the others are put on a waiting list.

So let's say everyone with a gmail adress get's access and I want the rest to be redirected to the page /waiting list.

---

*Example:*

**Gmail user:**

```
Route::get('favorites', 'FavoriteController@index');
```

**Hotmail user:**

```
Route::get('favorites', 'FavoriteController@index')
```

*-> let this redirect to*

```
Route::get('waitlist', 'WaitlistController@index')
```

---

Is there an easy, short way to do this for every route, for example with an if, like this?

```
if(substr($user->email, -9)!= "@gmail.com")
{
    always redirect my routes to "Waitlist"
}
```

Comment: I would do this logic in your sign-in function. :)

Comment: If you need help let me know. Post your sign-in function. I'll help you.

Comment: @ihue but then what if a users manually gives in the url?

Comment: Ohh. No. They can't. Post your sign-in function.

Comment: You check it when they submit the form.

Comment: @ihue yes but I mean, what if I login, i get redirected to the waiting list. But when I manually enter www.project.dev/articles I can still acces that page. I want it to redirect to www.project.dev/waitinglist for hotmails users.

Comment: You can create a middleware for that. If their email is end in hotmail block a certain URL. If they try go to it, you can redirect them to where ever you want.

Comment: @ihue and how do I do that? or where can I find info about that? I think that's the answer to my question!

Comment: @ihue found the solution, thanks for your help

Comment: Anytime. I'm glad I can help. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

alright so thanks to the user @ihue I know the solution.

I had to create a middelware that checked the user's email everytime they entered an URL.

**Here's how I did it**

---

I generated the middleware by using

```
php artisan make:middleware EmailRedirectMiddleware
```

---

Then in the middleware I coded my if loop.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Auth;
use Closure;

class EmailRedirectMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $user = Auth::User();
        if(substr($user->email, -9) != "@gmail.com")
        {
            return redirect('waitinglist');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

---

Then simply in your `routes.php`, use the middleware for every route you want, like this.

```
Route::group(array('middleware' => 'auth'), function(){
    Route::group(array('middleware' => 'App\Http\Middleware\EmailRedirectMiddleware'), function() {
        Route::get('work', 'WorkController@index');
    });
});
```

The first line checks if the users is logged in, the second line checks which email the logged in user has. 
If the user is not using a Gmail address he will be redirect to `waitinglist` like i coded in the Middleware

Answer (score 0):

you can change user redirect for multi users in following function.
 But incase of laravel version update your change in here may be canceled.

go to the file path and change function

> vendor\laravel\framework\src\illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUser.php

```
protected function handleUserWasAuthenticated(Request $request, $throttles)
    {
        if ($throttles) {
            $this->clearLoginAttempts($request);
        }

        if (method_exists($this, 'authenticated')) {
            return $this->authenticated($request, Auth::user());
        }

        $user = Auth::user();
        $type = $user->Rtype;

        if($type==1){
            return redirect()->intended('/admin/dashboard');
        }elseif($type==2){
            return redirect()->intended('/admin/dashboard');
        }elseif($type==3){
            return redirect()->intended('/');
        }else{
        return redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
        }

    }
```